# No marked answer when user found it usefull

Tags: support, accepted-answer, users

I have seen several questions, already inactive, for which an answer was given which was useful to the user asking, but not marked as the answer. It was easy to see they were useful from the comments and flags from the user asking. But since they seem long time inactive, I wonder what happens with these questions ultimately? Do they get closed? And also it seems they are even abandoned by the rest of the users, no new votes or flags. It would be strange that they are not visited any more by anyone.

Should there be a strategy to deal with this?

Some examples of what I mention...

[Example Question 1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3488/why-do-things-that-are-far-away-seem-smaller)

[Example Question 2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3505/free-electrons-and-energy-states)

[Example Question 3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3554/whats-a-good-reference-for-this-classical-picture-feynmans-talking-about)

[Example Question 4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/why-does-pressure-act-as-a-source-for-the-gravitational-field)

[Example Question 5](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/the-source-of-the-light-we-see-from-the-sun)

Comment: Related and possibly a duplicate: [Questions with no accepted answers?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5660/)

Comment: Indeed, almost the same. But it does not seem to be addressed as a problem. The answer given to this question proposes user-based behaviour. I think it doesn't solve the issue. What if there was a motivation for providing feedback? A badge or something? It seems that these are useful in other aspects like promoting editing and so. Why not promote feedback as well?

Comment: There is a reward. You get (I think) 2 rep points for accepting an answer. The reality is that many users simply don't care, and chasing them is likely to prove fruitless.

Comment: @JohnRennie I really do think this is a (frustrating) issue though, that perhaps should be dealt with somehow.

Comment: @Danu: Any method proposed has been rejected (e.g. [community-accepted feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)). It's also been discussed several times on meta (e.g., http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76183).

Comment: Very useful links @KyleKanos! I gained much insight about the related problems to this one. It strikes me though that no agreement has been reached about a solution, yet users keep raising it. But I see that there are many cases in this. I think it will be useful to review the inputs from the community and propose a solution based on this more solid grounds. I will post it as an answer to this question to put it at consideration of the community.

Comment: *no agreement has been reached about a solution* That is not the conclusion I came to; I find that the agreement is that there is nothing that can or should be done.